# Nexus one gapps not working ( Evervolv 4.2 JellyBean)

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-one

So I have phone (Google nexus one) with installed Evervolv 4.2 (Jelly bean), and I want google apps to be installed. But when I try to install them, either error pops up "Setup wizard has stopped" or nothing happens ( no apps installed ). What do I need to do? Where can I get good gapps to install?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your GApps archive matches your Android version? As you did not point out what GApps package you installed, that's just a guess.